# Why do my owner data list view state images come up as blank on Windows XP?

Tags: c, listview, winapi, windows-xp

Simple problem this time, but one I'm not seeing on searches: I have a list view control with state images that should show up in one column. In wine, Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8.1, things look correct. But in Windows XP, the state images don't show up, showing only white space where the image should be. Common Controls version 6 required. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample program that demonstrates this.

```
// 17 august 2014
// scratch Windows program by pietro gagliardi 17 april 2014
// fixed typos and added toWideString() 1 may 2014
// borrows code from the scratch GTK+ program (16-17 april 2014) and from code written 31 march 2014 and 11-12 april 2014
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define _GNU_SOURCE     // needed to declare asprintf()/vasprintf()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>       // needed for InitCommonControlsEx() (thanks Xeek in irc.freenode.net/#winapi for confirming)

#ifdef  _MSC_VER
#error sorry! the scratch windows program relies on mingw-only functionality! (specifically: asprintf())
#endif

HMODULE hInstance;
HICON hDefaultIcon;
HCURSOR hDefaultCursor;
HFONT controlfont;

void panic(char *fmt, ...);
TCHAR *toWideString(char *what);
void init(void);

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    NMHDR *nmhdr = (NMHDR *) lparam;
    NMLVDISPINFOW *fill = (NMLVDISPINFO *) lparam;

    switch (msg) {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        if (nmhdr->code == LVN_GETDISPINFO) {
            if (fill->item.iSubItem == 0) {
                fill->item.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(fill->item.iItem + 1);
                fill->item.stateMask = LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
            } else
                fill->item.pszText = L"No State Image Here";
            return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }
    panic("oops: message %ud does not return anything; bug in wndproc()", msg);
}

HWND makeMainWindow(void)
{
    WNDCLASS cls;
    HWND hwnd;

    ZeroMemory(&cls, sizeof (WNDCLASS));
    cls.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    cls.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    cls.hInstance = hInstance;
    cls.hIcon = hDefaultIcon;
    cls.hCursor = hDefaultCursor;
    cls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    if (RegisterClass(&cls) == 0)
        panic("error registering window class");
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        300, 300,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (hwnd == NULL)
        panic("opening main window failed");
    return hwnd;
}

void buildUI(HWND mainwin)
{
#define CSTYLE (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE)
#define CXSTYLE (0)
#define SETFONT(hwnd) SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) controlfont, (LPARAM) TRUE);

    HWND lv;
    LVCOLUMN column;
    HIMAGELIST imglist;

    lv = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | CXSTYLE,
        WC_LISTVIEW, L"",
        LVS_REPORT | LVS_OWNERDATA | LVS_NOSORTHEADER | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | CSTYLE,
        10, 10, 250, 250,
        mainwin, (HMENU) 100, hInstance, NULL);
    if (lv == NULL)
        panic("error making list view");
    SETFONT(lv);
    SendMessageW(lv, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,
        LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES,
        LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES);

    // error checking elided from this point to where otherwise noted

    imglist = ImageList_Create(
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
        ILC_COLOR32, 20, 20);
    ImageList_AddIcon(imglist, LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_ERROR));
    ImageList_AddIcon(imglist, LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_QUESTION));
    ImageList_AddIcon(imglist, LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_WARNING));
    SendMessageW(lv, LVM_SETIMAGELIST, LVSIL_STATE, (LPARAM) imglist);

    ZeroMemory(&column, sizeof (LVCOLUMN));
    column.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_ORDER;
    column.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    column.pszText = L"State Image";
    column.iSubItem = 0;
    column.iOrder = 0;
    SendMessageW(lv, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, 0, (LPARAM) (&column));
    ZeroMemory(&column, sizeof (LVCOLUMN));
    column.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_ORDER;
    column.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    column.pszText = L"No State Image";
    column.iSubItem = 1;
    column.iOrder = 1;
    SendMessageW(lv, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, 1, (LPARAM) (&column));

    // end of error eliding

    if (SendMessageW(lv, LVM_SETITEMCOUNT, 3, 0) == 0)
        panic("error setting number of items in list view");
}

void firstShowWindow(HWND hwnd);

int main(void)
{
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;

    init();

    mainwin = makeMainWindow();
    buildUI(mainwin);
    firstShowWindow(mainwin);

    for (;;) {
        BOOL gmret;

        gmret = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (gmret == -1)
            panic("error getting message");
        if (gmret == 0)
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD iccFlags =
//  ICC_ANIMATE_CLASS |         // animation control
//  ICC_BAR_CLASSES |               // toolbar, statusbar, trackbar, tooltip
//  ICC_COOL_CLASSES |          // rebar
//  ICC_DATE_CLASSES |          // date and time picker
//  ICC_HOTKEY_CLASS |          // hot key
//  ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES |      // IP address entry field
//  ICC_LINK_CLASS |                // hyperlink
    ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES |          // list-view, header
//  ICC_NATIVEFNTCTL_CLASS |        // native font
//  ICC_PAGESCROLLER_CLASS |        // pager
//  ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS |            // progress bar
//  ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES |      // "one of the intrinsic User32 control classes"
//  ICC_TAB_CLASSES |               // tab, tooltip
//  ICC_TREEVIEW_CLASSES |      // tree-view, tooltip
//  ICC_UPDOWN_CLASS |          // up-down
//  ICC_USEREX_CLASSES |            // ComboBoxEx
//  ICC_WIN95_CLASSES |         // some of the above
    0;

void init(void)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (hInstance == NULL)
        panic("error getting hInstance");
    hDefaultIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    if (hDefaultIcon == NULL)
        panic("error getting default window class icon");
    hDefaultCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
    if (hDefaultCursor == NULL)
        panic("error getting default window cursor");
    icc.dwSize = sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icc.dwICC = iccFlags;
    if (InitCommonControlsEx(&icc) == FALSE)
        panic("error initializing Common Controls");
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof (NONCLIENTMETRICS);
    if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS,
        sizeof (NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0) == 0)
        panic("error getting non-client metrics for getting control font");
    controlfont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
    if (controlfont == NULL)
        panic("error getting control font");
}

void panic(char *fmt, ...)
{
    char *msg;
    TCHAR *lerrmsg;
    char *fullmsg;
    va_list arg;
    DWORD lasterr;
    DWORD lerrsuccess;

    lasterr = GetLastError();
    va_start(arg, fmt);
    if (vasprintf(&msg, fmt, arg) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "critical error: vasprintf() failed in panic() preparing panic message; fmt = \"%s\"\n", fmt);
        abort();
    }
    // according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    lerrsuccess = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, lasterr,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lerrmsg, 0, NULL);
    if (lerrsuccess == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "critical error: FormatMessage() failed in panic() preparing GetLastError() string; panic message = \"%s\", last error in panic(): %ld, last error from FormatMessage(): %ld\n", msg, lasterr, GetLastError());
        abort();
    }
    // note to self: use %ws instead of %S (thanks jon_y in irc.oftc.net/#mingw-w64)
    if (asprintf(&fullmsg, "panic: %s\nlast error: %ws\n", msg, lerrmsg) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "critical error: asprintf() failed in panic() preparing full report; panic message = \"%s\", last error message: \"%ws\"\n", msg, lerrmsg);
        abort();
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", fullmsg);
    va_end(arg);
    exit(1);
}

void firstShowWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    // we need to get nCmdShow
    int nCmdShow;
    STARTUPINFO si;

    nCmdShow = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
    GetStartupInfo(&si);
    if ((si.dwFlags & STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW) != 0)
        nCmdShow = si.wShowWindow;
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    if (UpdateWindow(hwnd) == 0)
        panic("UpdateWindow(hwnd) failed in first show");
}

TCHAR *toWideString(char *what)
{
    TCHAR *buf;
    int n;
    size_t len;

    len = strlen(what);
    if (len == 0) {
        buf = (TCHAR *) malloc(sizeof (TCHAR));
        if (buf == NULL)
            goto mallocfail;
        buf[0] = L'\0';
    } else {
        n = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, what, -1, NULL, 0);
        if (n == 0)
            panic("error getting number of bytes to convert \"%s\" to UTF-16", what);
        buf = (TCHAR *) malloc((n + 1) * sizeof (TCHAR));
        if (buf == NULL)
            goto mallocfail;
        if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, what, -1, buf, n) == 0)
            panic("erorr converting \"%s\" to UTF-16", what);
    }
    return buf;
mallocfail:
    panic("error allocating memory for UTF-16 version of \"%s\"", what);
}
```

Comment: You may need to use the `LVM_SETCALLBACKMASK` message to get the listview to request item state data.

Comment: Well you've done it again. I wonder if we will ever fully understand this control =P If you could answer both questions I can formally check them as required. Thanks again!

Comment: The listview is probably the most complex common control and also one of the weirdest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listview control uses `LVM_SETCALLBACKMASK` to make it request item state data via `LVN_GETDISPINFO`.

I can only guess that on Windows 7 and upwards this requirement was removed for owner data controls - the docs don't say - but in XP/Vista you need to send this message to have it request item state.

Comment: Right; turns out I was wrong about Vista without Common Controls 6; I'm guessing it was comctl6 on Vista that removed the restriction :/ Either way, thanks again!